# Possible to combine these two queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two cypher queries and would like to know if there is a possibility to get the Points and HeadHunter information within one single statement.

```
MATCH (s:SEASON)-[*]->(e:EVENT)<-[f:FINISHED]-(p:PLAYER)
    WHERE s.id = 8 AND e.id <= 1197
    RETURN p, sum(f.points) AS Points
    ORDER BY Points DESC

MATCH (s:SEASON)-[*]->(e:EVENT)<-[el:ELIMINATED]-(p:PLAYER)
    WHERE s.id = 8 AND e.id <= 1197
    RETURN p, sum(el.points) AS HeadHunter
    ORDER BY HeadHunter DESC
```

I played around with different approaches but none of them worked. I would like to do something like this:

```
MATCH (s:SEASON)-[*]->(e:EVENT)<-[el:ELIMINATED]-(p:PLAYER),(e)<-[f:FINISHED]-(p)
    WHERE s.id = 8 AND e.id <= 1197
    RETURN p, sum(el.points) AS HeadHunter, sum(f.points) AS Points
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (s:SEASON)-[*]->(e:EVENT)<-[rel:FINISHED|ELIMINATED]-(p:PLAYER)
WHERE s.id = 8 AND e.id <= 1197
WITH p, COLLECT(rel) AS rels
RETURN p,
  REDUCE(s = 0, x IN rels | CASE WHEN TYPE(x) = 'FINISHED' THEN s + x.points ELSE s END) AS Points,
  REDUCE(s = 0, x IN rels | CASE WHEN TYPE(x) = 'ELIMINATED' THEN s + x.points ELSE s END) AS HeadHunter
```

This should return the relevant sums for each PLAYER that either finished and/or got eliminated.

Comment: Looks very promissing. I'll try the solution later today and give you a feedback if it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In principle I think your query can work, but you may have made a mistake with your `p` variable.  In this query:

```
MATCH (s:SEASON)-[*]->(e:EVENT)<-[el:ELIMINATED]-(p:PLAYER),(e)<-[f:FINISHED]-(p)
    WHERE s.id = 8 AND e.id <= 1197
    RETURN p, sum(el.points) AS HeadHunter, sum(f.points) AS Points
```

Note that `p` has to be a player with both the `ELIMINATED` relationship **and** the `FINISHED` relationship.  I'm guessing based on the semantics of your domain, that doesn't make sense; you can't be  eliminated and have finished, right?

So you might want to try some variant of this:

```
MATCH (s:SEASON)-[*]->(e:EVENT)<-[el:ELIMINATED]-(pElim:PLAYER),(e)<-[f:FINISHED]-(pFinish)
    WHERE s.id = 8 AND e.id <= 1197
    RETURN pElim, sum(el.points) AS HeadHunter, pFinish, sum(f.points) AS Points
```

Note with this you'll have a lot of extra rows of output for various combinations of `pElim` and `pFinish` but the respective values should be correct.

Comment: This query only matches Events that have both an ELIMINATED relationship and a FINISHED relationship. Although better than the original query, that may still not be appropriate.

Comment: Ah, so OP was looking for independence of `Event` objects too?  The actual  model requirements in the original question were kind of vague.

Comment: Sorry @FrobberOfBits if I was a little bit unclear about my usecase and how the nodes are connected 'logically'. I'm fairly new to all the graph database stuff and might have to figure out which information is relevant to ask my questions unmistakable.